# Is accessing HTML tags in behind code in a static method possible?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, code-behind

I can't find a simple answer to this anywhere on the web.

What i'm trying to do is running c# code when ever i click a certain HTML button   with

```
onclick="<%MethodName()%>"
```

that will collect data from a database and present it on html tags.

Static methods are the only kind i currently know how to use, and never had to deal with one that needs to use SQL as well.
Problem is, i can't use most of the commands i need to use in a standard static method, nor will it recognize html tags and System.Data variables.

I could however run the code on Page_Load but i don't understand why would i do that if there's a possibility i'm never gonna need to use that information.

If anyone could supply me with an answer on how to use these type of commands in static methods (or show me a better way) that would be spectacular! Thanks in advance!

Comment: that's not how this works.  that's not how any of this works.

Comment: @Will How about instead of just saying "This is wrong" show me how can you do it right?...

Comment: I'd like to, but that involves kind of a book to explain :/  Someone who's using classic ASP.NET may have an easy solution for posting back and running a method on the server from a button click event, but it's been years and years since I've used it.  I'm not even sure if you understand how everything works together, such as the distinctions between server side and client side code, and how asp.net uses the viewstate to simulate events on the server side... My real advice would be punt and go ASP.NET MVC, but that's not an answer to *this*.